# C# app flagged in virus total "Contacted IP Addresses" don't know why

Tags: c#, .net, ip, virus-scanning

I have created an application in C# that is just about ready to hit production, just off the top of my head I thought I had better upload this to virus total to make sure there are no False-Positives, 2 antivirus's threw false positives, however on the behaviour tab I saw something that really concerned me, The application apparently according to virustotal connects to 3 IP's

13.107.4.52

20.189.173.20

23.216.147.64

This makes little sense to me as I have no networking code in the application and ive tripple checked all the code and cant find anything that could be doing this...
Quite puzzled, does anyone have any solutions as to why it is apparently trying to connect to these IP's?

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/55eaeb46ee13d69a49815b85ee9cdee85429a7698b7303cbe206a824f7800a79/relations

Comment: Your app is using **GriceLib, WinFormAnimation,** and **CircularProgressBar**.  Maybe one of them is responsible.   Make a MVP app with one of each in turn to track down the culprit.

Comment: GriceLib is my own library I have built, but good idea ill get back to you with the results, Thanks MickyD!

Comment: I have no idea anymore haha, seems a blank new project with nothing in it is also pulling similar stuff.

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/7ad234188556102517ca8f761c5ba953b5f476300fb7ae0db4448b36b1eedff2/relations

this is 100% blank, new project, build upload.... :/

Comment: Please define “blank, new project.” Which .NET version? Console, WPF, WinForms…? Those IPs belong to Microsoft and Akamai at least

Comment: sure thing thanks :), its a winforms project, using dotnet framework 4.7.2

Comment: Hmmm....it seems that tool isn't particularly useful if it simply reports IP addresses but fails to follow-up with a _"...oh and btw, those are known good IPs..."_ - or some such.

Comment: It's not a problem since they are both owned by Microsoft, perhaps it is some kind of updater built into dotnet framework